# Installation via openstack (yoga) ansible fail

Tags: networking, ansible, openstack, lxc

I am testing openstack on 4 computers: 1 deploy, 3 hosts.

The 3 hosts have 2 nics each, one for the connectivity with the lan, the other only for openstack, which mean for exemple, that enp2s0 is on the dhcp 172.16.0.1/12 (lan), enp3s0 is openstack only (see configuration for each machine below). It is configured like a single nic style on enp3s0.

The deploy computer, is with one nic. No specific configuration has been added.

According to the setup manual, the first thing I have to do is `openstack-ansible setup-hosts.yml`, which complete without any problems. Then I execute `openstack-ansible setup-infrastructure.yml` which crash at the task `Get list of repo packages`.

Ansible give this reason:  `fatal: [infra1_utility_container-4c9c698c]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "content": "", "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "http://172.29.236.11:8181/constraints/upper_constraints_cached.txt"}`.

I don’t understand why the connectivity to the utility container disappear. I went on the infra computer, and this container is started, iptables is on ACCEPT by default. I don’t have the beginning of an idea of what is wrong.

Here is the user configuration used :

```
---
cidr_networks:
  container: 172.29.236.0/22
  tunnel: 172.29.240.0/22
  storage: 172.29.244.0/22

used_ips:
  - "172.29.236.1,172.29.236.50"
  - "172.29.240.1,172.29.240.50"
  - "172.29.244.1,172.29.244.50"
  - "172.29.248.1,172.29.248.50"

global_overrides:
  # The internal and external VIP should be different IPs, however they
  # do not need to be on separate networks.
  external_lb_vip_address: 172.29.236.11
  internal_lb_vip_address: 172.29.236.11
  management_bridge: "br-mgmt"
  provider_networks:
    - network:
        container_bridge: "br-mgmt"
        container_type: "veth"
        container_interface: "eth1"
        ip_from_q: "container"
        type: "raw"
        group_binds:
          - all_containers
          - hosts
        is_container_address: true
    - network:
        container_bridge: "br-vxlan"
        container_type: "veth"
        container_interface: "eth10"
        ip_from_q: "tunnel"
        type: "vxlan"
        range: "1:1000"
        net_name: "vxlan"
        group_binds:
          - neutron_linuxbridge_agent
    - network:
        container_bridge: "br-vlan"
        container_type: "veth"
        container_interface: "eth12"
        host_bind_override: "eth12"
        type: "flat"
        net_name: "flat"
        group_binds:
          - neutron_linuxbridge_agent
    - network:
        container_bridge: "br-vlan"
        container_type: "veth"
        container_interface: "eth11"
        type: "vlan"
        range: "101:200,301:400"
        net_name: "vlan"
        group_binds:
          - neutron_linuxbridge_agent
    - network:
        container_bridge: "br-storage"
        container_type: "veth"
        container_interface: "eth2"
        ip_from_q: "storage"
        type: "raw"
        group_binds:
          - glance_api
          - cinder_api
          - cinder_volume
          - nova_compute

###
### Infrastructure
###

# galera, memcache, rabbitmq, utility
shared-infra_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 172.29.236.11

# repository (apt cache, python packages, etc)
repo-infra_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 172.29.236.11
    
os-infra_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 172.29.236.11

# load balancer
# haproxy_hosts:
  # infra1:
    # ip: 172.29.236.11

###
### OpenStack
###

# keystone
identity_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 172.29.236.11

# cinder api services
storage-infra_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 172.29.236.11

# glance
image_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 172.29.236.11

# placement
placement-infra_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 172.29.236.11

# nova api, conductor, etc services
compute-infra_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 172.29.236.11

# heat
orchestration_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 172.29.236.11

# horizon
dashboard_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 172.29.236.11

# neutron server, agents (L3, etc)
network_hosts:
  infra1:
    ip: 172.29.236.11

# nova hypervisors
compute_hosts:
  compute1:
    ip: 172.29.236.12

# cinder storage host (LVM-backed)
storage_hosts:
  storage1:
    ip: 172.29.244.18
    container_vars:
      cinder_backends:
        limit_container_types: cinder_volume
        lvm:
          volume_group: cinder-volumes
          volume_driver: cinder.volume.drivers.lvm.LVMVolumeDriver
          volume_backend_name: LVM_iSCSI
          iscsi_ip_address: "172.29.244.18"
```

The infra computer network configuration :

```
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet manual

# Container/Host management VLAN interface
auto enp3s0.10
iface enp3s0.10 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device enp3s0

# OpenStack Networking VXLAN (tunnel/overlay) VLAN interface
auto enp3s0.30
iface enp3s0.30 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device enp3s0

# Storage network VLAN interface (optional)
auto enp3s0.20
iface enp3s0.20 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device enp3s0

# Container/Host management bridge
auto br-mgmt
iface br-mgmt inet static
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports enp3s0.10
    address 172.29.236.11
    netmask 255.255.252.0
#    gateway 172.29.236.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# OpenStack Networking VXLAN (tunnel/overlay) bridge
#
# Nodes hosting Neutron agents must have an IP address on this interface,
# including COMPUTE, NETWORK, and collapsed INFRA/NETWORK nodes.
#

auto br-vxlan
iface br-vxlan inet static
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports enp3s0.30
    address 172.29.240.16
    netmask 255.255.252.0

# OpenStack Networking VLAN bridge
#
# The "br-vlan" bridge is no longer necessary for deployments unless Neutron
# agents are deployed in a container. Instead, a direct interface such as
# enp3s0 can be specified via the "host_bind_override" override when defining
# provider networks.
#
#auto br-vlan
#iface br-vlan inet manual
#    bridge_stp off
#    bridge_waitport 0
#    bridge_fd 0
#    bridge_ports enp3s0

# compute1 Network VLAN bridge
#auto br-vlan
#iface br-vlan inet manual
#    bridge_stp off
#    bridge_waitport 0
#    bridge_fd 0
#

# Storage bridge (optional)
#
# Only the COMPUTE and STORAGE nodes must have an IP address
# on this bridge. When used by infrastructure nodes, the
# IP addresses are assigned to containers which use this
# bridge.
#
auto br-storage
iface br-storage inet manual
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports enp3s0.20

# compute1 Storage bridge
#auto br-storage
#iface br-storage inet static
#    bridge_stp off
#    bridge_waitport 0
#    bridge_fd 0
#    bridge_ports enp3s0.20
#    address 172.29.244.16
#    netmask 255.255.252.0
```

The compute computer network configuration :

```
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet manual

# Container/Host management VLAN interface
auto enp3s0.10
iface enp3s0.10 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device enp3s0

# OpenStack Networking VXLAN (tunnel/overlay) VLAN interface
auto enp3s0.30
iface enp3s0.30 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device enp3s0

# Storage network VLAN interface (optional)
auto enp3s0.20
iface enp3s0.20 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device enp3s0

# Container/Host management bridge
auto br-mgmt
iface br-mgmt inet static
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports enp3s0.10
    address 172.29.236.12
    netmask 255.255.252.0
#    gateway 172.29.236.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# OpenStack Networking VXLAN (tunnel/overlay) bridge
#
# Nodes hosting Neutron agents must have an IP address on this interface,
# including COMPUTE, NETWORK, and collapsed INFRA/NETWORK nodes.
#

auto br-vxlan
iface br-vxlan inet static
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports enp3s0.30
    address 172.29.240.17
    netmask 255.255.252.0

# OpenStack Networking VLAN bridge
#
# The "br-vlan" bridge is no longer necessary for deployments unless Neutron
# agents are deployed in a container. Instead, a direct interface such as
# bond0 can be specified via the "host_bind_override" override when defining
# provider networks.
#
#auto br-vlan
#iface br-vlan inet manual
#    bridge_stp off
#    bridge_waitport 0
#    bridge_fd 0
#    bridge_ports bond0

# compute1 Network VLAN bridge
#auto br-vlan
#iface br-vlan inet manual
#    bridge_stp off
#    bridge_waitport 0
#    bridge_fd 0
#

# Storage bridge (optional)
#
# Only the COMPUTE and STORAGE nodes must have an IP address
# on this bridge. When used by infrastructure nodes, the
# IP addresses are assigned to containers which use this
# bridge.
#
#auto br-storage
#iface br-storage inet manual
#    bridge_stp off
#    bridge_waitport 0
#    bridge_fd 0
#    bridge_ports bond0.20

# compute1 Storage bridge
auto br-storage
iface br-storage inet static
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports enp3s0.20
    address 172.29.244.17
    netmask 255.255.252.0
```

The storage computer network configuration :

```
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet manual

# Container/Host management VLAN interface
auto enp2s0.10
iface enp2s0.10 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device enp2s0

# OpenStack Networking VXLAN (tunnel/overlay) VLAN interface
auto enp2s0.30
iface enp2s0.30 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device enp2s0

# Storage network VLAN interface (optional)
auto enp2s0.20
iface enp2s0.20 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device enp2s0

# Container/Host management bridge
auto br-mgmt
iface br-mgmt inet static
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports enp2s0.10
    address 172.29.236.13
    netmask 255.255.252.0
#    gateway 172.16.0.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# OpenStack Networking VXLAN (tunnel/overlay) bridge
#
# Nodes hosting Neutron agents must have an IP address on this interface,
# including COMPUTE, NETWORK, and collapsed INFRA/NETWORK nodes.
#

auto br-vxlan
iface br-vxlan inet static
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports enp2s0.30
    address 172.29.240.18
    netmask 255.255.252.0

# OpenStack Networking VLAN bridge
#
# The "br-vlan" bridge is no longer necessary for deployments unless Neutron
# agents are deployed in a container. Instead, a direct interface such as
# enp2s0 can be specified via the "host_bind_override" override when defining
# provider networks.
#
#auto br-vlan
#iface br-vlan inet manual
#    bridge_stp off
#    bridge_waitport 0
#    bridge_fd 0
#    bridge_ports enp2s0

# compute1 Network VLAN bridge
#auto br-vlan
#iface br-vlan inet manual
#    bridge_stp off
#    bridge_waitport 0
#    bridge_fd 0
#

# Storage bridge (optional)
#
# Only the COMPUTE and STORAGE nodes must have an IP address
# on this bridge. When used by infrastructure nodes, the
# IP addresses are assigned to containers which use this
# bridge.
#
#auto br-storage
#iface br-storage inet manual
#    bridge_stp off
#    bridge_waitport 0
#    bridge_fd 0
#    bridge_ports enp2s0.20

# compute1 Storage bridge
auto br-storage
iface br-storage inet static
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports enp2s0.20
    address 172.29.244.18
    netmask 255.255.252.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means the repo server is unavailable at 172.29.236.11:8181 even if the utility container is running.

I had this same error and it turned out to be some of my netmasks were incorrect. Please double check your CIDR settings in /etc/openstack_deploy/user_variables.yml and /etc/openstack_deploy/openstack_user_config.yml! Some of the defaults in online examples are pretty wild.